# reqParam = $.getQueryParameters(); what this request do in ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I already do so much search but i failed to find what is `reqParam = $.getQueryParameters();` this code mean and what is use in ajax java script. I have copy a java script code from someone website example. Please if you have any idea then help me i already used like `reqParam = jQuery.getQueryParameters();` but it's also not working my full js code is here.

```
showSearch = function(evt){

    }).done(function(data){
        if(data.message){
            showMessage(data); return;
        }
};
```

Comment: It is used to address URL query string as named key / value pair https://github.com/youbastard/jquery.getQueryParameters

Comment: so how i get value of these because i'm getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: $.getQueryParameters is not a function`
   `at showSearchResult (profiles.js:222)`
    `at dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)`
    `at r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)`

Comment: Ajay Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function does not seem to exist, you can add it with:

```
$.getQueryParameters = function(str) {
  return (str || document.location.search).replace(/(^\?)/,'').split("&")
  .reduce(
    function(all,part){
      part=part.split("=");
      all[part[0]]=part[1];
      return all;
    },
    {}
  );
};
```

Maybe it existed in a very old version of jQuery or you are missing an extension.

Comment: ok but its showing one error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`  in `$.getQueryParameters = function(str) {`

Comment: Or How i replace this code with latest jquery code ..?

Comment: @Deepak try to copy and paste the code again but do it right this time.

Comment: This code work if i remove `$.` But with `$.` Showing error